# Can't Submit FormData via Axios

Tags: vuejs2

I am using vue-form-wizard for a large 5 panel form and the specs are that there are no “additional submit buttons” other than the wizard’s Next button … I have 4 of the 5 panels licked but the last panel is kicking my butt.

It is a panel where 6 documents are uploaded. I wrapped just that panel in a form tag (the other panel submit via axios) like this:

```
<tab-content title="Documents" :before-change="docs_next">
    <form id="frmDocs" @submit.prevent="documentsUpload”>
```

docs_next is the method that this panel runs when the wizard’s next button is clicked

```
docs_next() { 
    document.getElementById('frmDocs').submit();
     return true;
 },
 documentsUpload() {
     alert('Form Submitting');
}
```

This is to test the submit and the alert is not firing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Executing `submit()` will not trigger a *submit* event on the form element

Comment: ```document.forms["frmDocs"].submit();``` ???